# reactjs, how to pass props at the class level

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is an example of what im trying to do. I want to pass in props at the MyComponent class, without using `<MyComponent hello={'Hello World'}/>`, because I am passing MyComponent to some other libraries.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { hello } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>{hello}</div>
    );
  }
}

// this line is wrong
MyComponent.props = {
  hello: 'Hello World!'
}

<MyComponent />
```

How is react-redux connect to add this.props.state, and map any other functions to the component's props? I want to inject my custom objects into a component.

Comment: Think about what you're asking. You want to pass in props, without passing in props. No: that is not how you use React's methodology. In your example, just say `let props = { ... }` and then use `<MyComponent {... props} />` because that is fine: there is no reason to not want to do this that actually makes sense from a programming point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

```
function withMyObject(WrappedComponent,helloText) {
  return class extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} hello={helloText} />;
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
UpdatedComponent = withMyObject(ComponentToBeWrapped,"Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set default props. I think its a good practice.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { hello } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>{hello}</div>
    );
  }headerProp: "Header from props...",
   contentProp:"Content from props..."
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
   hello: 'Hello World!'
}

<MyComponent />
```